# Get error in R when try to use function get() twice in %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach, get, doparallel

I have a data frame with name 'data_frame' which I want to use in computations with the library `doParallel`. I try the following:

```
library(doParallel)
myCluster <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)


system.time({
  list_input_tmp <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(get('data_frame'))) %dopar% {
    temp = list(function1(get('data_frame')[i,]), get('data_frame')[i,])
  }
})

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

But I get the error

> Error in { :
> task 1 failed - "object 'data_frame' not found" Timing stopped at: 0.18 0.06 1.45

However it works if I use:

```
library(doParallel)
myCluster <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)


system.time({
  list_input_tmp <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(get('data_frame'))) %dopar% {
    temp = list(function1(data_frame[i,])), get('data_frame')[i,])
  }
})

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

Or

```
library(doParallel)
myCluster <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)


system.time({
  list_input_tmp <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(get(paste0('data_',list_input[3])))) %dopar% {
    temp = list(function1(get('data_frame')[i,]), data_frame[i,])
  }
})

stopCluster(myCluster)
```

Does anyone have any experience from this problem?

Regards Dan

Comment: Why `paste("data_frame")`? Why not `"data_frame"`? While I don't have a lot of experience with `foreach`, my guess is that any attempts to auto-parse the expression to determine which variables to transfer will *not* handle strings, even if they are within the obvious `get` function. Again, I might be wrong. Can you replace `get(...)` with just `data_frame` (no string, no quotes, no `get`)?

Comment: I can use data_frame and it will return the correct result, but I am trying to read a list of data_frames dynamically from an external source and I want to use the names of the data_frames so I dont ahve to duplicate code. I tried to extract the problem to make it simpler.